# How to enter and use a variable in the middle of "New-Item" in powershell

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to create a simple program that copies files from one location to another. I got that part down just find but I'd like to as ask for user input as to a set aspect to the path I need to create a new folder at.

For example

Ask for user input and store that name in a variable. Then use that variable in the path to create a new folder called test

```
$inputName = Read-Host 'Enter computer name'
New-Item C:\Users\$inputName\Documents\test -type directory | Out-Null
```

So if there were multiple users on a computer you could ask which user\documents you would create the new document in.

Very much still learning/teaching myself powershell so sorry if it's something I'm totally missing! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Worth mentioning you can include two variables in your `New-Item` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Edit 2, adding notes about CmdletBinding options.  And if you leave out the params, powershell prompts for input.

```
Function My-Test{
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
Param(
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
  [string]$Path,
 [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
  HelpMessage="Enter ServerName")]
  [String]$server,
)
My-Test -Path C:\Temp -server Server9000
```

-Edit to add PowerShell will expand variables between double quotes.  Single quotes on the other hand will write the `$path` as exactly that.

As an example:

```
Write-Host 'Your variable is $path`
 Your variable is $path
Write-Host "Your path is $path"
 Output: Your path is C:\Temp
```

You can use `Read-Host` to prompt the user to input something that's assigned to a variable.  Additionally, you can specify `AsSecureString` so the value stored is encrypted.

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter path name"
Write-Host "You chose $path"
```

Secondly, your script can begin with `param($path)` which will accept the path as a cmdline parameter.

```
PS C:\ > Script.ps1 -path "c:\temp"
```

Comment: Also if you use `[CmdletBinding()]` to treat your script like an advanced function, you can [make parameters Mandatory](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh847743.aspx). This means that if they aren't supplied at the time it's called, PowerShell will prompt the caller for you.

Comment: Oh, good point @briantist I'll edit my answer with this!  You can also include `HelpMessage="Enter Servername here!"` as well.